# How to streamline filtering in Mongo database

Tags: php, mongodb

I am attempting to filter a report by using two parameters (name and id) in a Mongo DB. The way I have it set up now is this:

```
// if both params are empty
if ((empty($filterParams['name'])) && (empty($filterParams['id']))) {
    $views = $mongoDb->selectCollection('views')->find([], []);
}
// if one of the two params are empty
if ((!empty($filterParams['name'])) || (!empty($filterParams['id']))) {
        // name is empty
        if ((empty($filterParams['name']))) {
            $idQuery = array('id' => (int)$filterParams['id']);
            $views = $mongoDb->selectCollection('views')->find($idQuery, []);
        }
        // id is empty
        if ((empty($filteredParams['id']))) {
            $nameQuery = array('name' => $filterParams['name']);
            $views = $mongoDb->selectCollection('views')->find($nameQuery, []);
        }
        // neither are empty
        if ((!empty($filterParams['name'])) && (!empty($filterParams['id']))) {
            $fullQuery = array('id' => (int)$filterParams['id'], 'name' => $filteredParams['name']);
            $views = $mongoDb->selectCollection('views')->find($fullQuery, []);
        }                
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to streamline this so that the insertion can be done one time without the multiple if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are of course overengineering a very simple problem. All you really need to do here is take your "filterParams" ( which is likely from a request source ) and convert a possible "string" value for "id" into the the "numeric" format your database seems to be expecting ( going by the code written here ).

```
  // $filterParams = array()      // or it might be blank
  $filterParams = array( "id" => "1", "something" => "else" );

  $query = array();

  foreach( $filterParams as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $key == "id" )
      $query[$key] = intval($value);

    $query[$key] = $filterParams[$key];

  }

  $views = $mongoDb->selectCollection('views')->find($query);
```

So just start with an empty object and simply add in or tranform the keys are required for the query. If there are no keys at all, then this is an "empty" query object as MongoDB expects, with one key or both, then the same thing would also be passed through. All you really "need" here is to cast a "string" into the expected type for a given field.

In fact, especially since "filterParams" seems to be void of other data you could just alter the values in place rather than define another structure.

```
  // $filterParams = array()      // or it might be blank
  $filterParams = array( "id" => "1", "something" => "else" );

  $query = array();

  foreach( $filterParams as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $key == "id" )
      $filterParams[$key] = intval($value);
  }

  $views = $mongoDb->selectCollection('views')->find($filterParams);
```

With most dynamic languages, MongoDB queries are really just data structures in the same format as what the language natively uses to express such things. So the basic principles apply to data structure manipulation anywhere.

Same JavaScript thing for example:

```js
//var filterParams = {};

var filterParams = {
  id: "1",
  something: "here"
};

Object.keys(filterParams).forEach(function(key) {
  if (key == "id" )
    filterParams[key] = parseInt(filterParams[key]);
});

db.collection.find(filterParams);
```

Also "id" is typically an identifier used for a "unique" value to an object, just as `_id` is always used by MongoDB. So consider that when this key is present, then all other possible query arguments become redundant, unless you "really" want to check that the correct identifier was presented with the other correct properties of the object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It was what I was looking for.